# String Parser for GoogleAppsScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following string that I need to pull out from an email body
"From: John Smith , Guardian/Caregiver School: Base Ridge, Texas Grade: 4"

I need to pull this into an excel in the format

FirstName|LastName|Email                |Type              |SchoolName|State |Grade

John     |Smith   |john.smith@wonder.net|Guardian/Caregiver|Base Ridge|Texas |4

I want to use this within GoogleAppsScript

Comment: Have you tried [tag:regex]?

Answer (score 1):

As Master suggested, you can use regex, for example

```js
var s="From: John Smith , Guardian/Caregiver School: Base Ridge, Texas Grade: 4";

var items=s.match(/From: (.*?) (.*?),(.*?) School:(.*?),(.*?) Grade: (\d+)/).map(x => x.trim())
items.shift();
console.log(items.join('|'));
```